# 403 access denied Spring Security everytime

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-aop

I am getting 403 on every request having pattern /admin
I need to restrict /admin only for admin role.

Failed approach :

1. Tried using `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('ADMIN'))` and `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'))` on controller but no luck.
2. Tried removing `@PreAuthorize` from controller and adding pattern in the below class with hasRole but no luck

Below is the class extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","ADMIN_TENANT")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
        httpSecurity.
            addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.
            headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
```

Already tried solutions mentioned in similar question but no luck.
So please don't mark it duplicate.

Comment: Can you access /admin related requests, when you remove the authorization completely? and also remove the HttpMethod.GET from the antmatchers and check

Comment: Yea, when removing /admin from antmatchers i am able to acces it, but i need authorization.

Comment: Can you use your antmatchers like this "antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')") "?

Comment: change hasAnyrole to hasAnyAuthority

Comment: Also tried changing it to hasAnyAuthority did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","ADMIN_TENANT") // change hasAnyrole to hasAnyAuthority
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
        httpSecurity.
            addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.
            headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
```

Comment: why because If you use hasAnyRole method it will automatically append Role_ to all the things mentioned in hasAnyRole

Answer (score 0):

**My similar Git Project**: [here](https://github.com/gauravs08/SpringBootSecurityJPA)

```
    // Config to check if already active
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .and() 
    .rememberMe()
    .tokenRepository(new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl().setDataSource(//datasource_name) )
     .tokenValiditySeconds(//TimeInterval in sec); 

}
```